# How to fetch data into JSON encode array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo, fetch

I am trying to fetch some column values (item, description, price etc) into these `json_encode` arrays.

Inside the arrays you can see the 'amount' string is the one I have attempted on.

I tried using `$value = $fetch['price'];` and then inside the array using `$value` but it doesn't accept it.

I also tried..

```
'amount' => ['price']

&

'amount' => "$fetch['price']"

&

'amount' => `$fetch['price']`

&

'amount' => {$fetch['price']}
```

I saw some other threads on stackoverflow showing that the fetch query maybe needs to be inside the `json_encode`? but that was too fetch all results and encode them whereas I already have the encoding so I'm not sure.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

```
$userdetails = $_SESSION['usr_name'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `username` = '$userdetails' ORDER BY `uid` DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(
array (
'name' => 'My-Business-Name',
'description' => "Selected Product: ",
'local_price' => 
array (
'amount' => $fetch['price'],
'currency' => 'GBP',
),
'pricing_type' => 'fixed_price',
'metadata' => 
array (
'customer_id' => 'uid_1',
'customer_name' => 'Satoshi Nakamoto',
)
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: `'amount' => ['price'],` is missing the `$fetch`. Have you made sure that `$fetch` actually contains the values?

Comment: @brombeer Yeah thats because I was just showing both different ways that I've tried doing it, neither work, yes `$fetch = stmt->fetchAll();`

Comment: Are you sure that your `$fetch` variable isn't indexed by rows? So you have `$fetch[0]['price']`?

Comment: @Robert Ohhh yes this fixed it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets do small refactoring and typo fixes

`$userdetails = $_SESSION[usr_name];`

It should be either `$_SESSION['usr_name']` or `$_SESSION[$usr_name]`.

Next thing

`` $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `username` = '$userdetails' ORDER BY `uid` DESC"); ``

The correct and safer way to use prepared statements is next([according to php pdo docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-1004))

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `username` = :username ORDER BY `uid` DESC");
$stmt->execute(array( ':username' => $userdetails ));
$fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

After this do something like **var_dump** or **print_r** on `$fetch` just to be sure that data is there as brombeer said.

Comment: Hi, Yeah the `$userdetails = $_SESSION['usr_name'];` is correct its just where I typed it on here, Also when I use `print_r` I am returning all the data from database.